# Application Role management

Tags: c#, asp.net

Need to implement  Application Role Management feature..
Looked at AZMan , I guess it is bit of a over kill for my application.
Thinking of using XML input , that has multiple hirarchay defining Roles. Given that some roles can participate (like Administrator) in all other (sub) roles.
Any recomondation highly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, you just need a role implementation that handles hierarchical roles.

One approach might be to implement a custom [RoleProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fw7xh74.aspx)

If you had your role database setup something like (could also be a hierarchical XML file)

```
ID  Role       ParentRoleID
1   Admin      null
2   SubAdmin1  1
3   SubAdmin2  1
```

You could code your custom role provider such that if a user is explicitly assigned the admin role, they are "behind the scenes" given the admin role **plus** any sub roles. In this example, for a user explicitly assigned the "Admin" role, the `GetRolesForUser` method would return "Admin, SubAdmin1, SubAdmin2".  In this way a call from your code to Roles.IsUserInRole("SubAdmin2") would return true for a user who was only explicitly assigned the "Admin" role.

HTH